# Segmentation fault error in iOS

Tags: ios, segmentation-fault

What are the ways to find location within code and cause of segmentation fault error in iOS,as exception debugger cant able to locate it.

Comment: From the description of the iOS tag: "Please follow the article [My App Crashed, Now What](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)? by Ray Wenderlich, before posting any questions relating to app crashes. It explains how to properly debug an iOS app."

Answer (score 1):

To identify the exact line in your code, disable Optimisation -O0 (None) in compiler Optimisation settings. Also enable testing and debugging in the Xcode settings.